# Hand Detection Using Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
%%skin detection
[hue,s,v]=rgb2hsv(I);
cb =  0.148* I(:,:,1) - 0.291* I(:,:,2) + 0.439 * I(:,:,3) + 128;
cr =  0.439 * I(:,:,1) - 0.368 * I(:,:,2) -0.071 * I(:,:,3) + 128;
[w h]=size(I(:,:,1));
for i=1:w
  for j=1:h    
      if  128<=cr(i,j) && cr(i,j)<=165 && 140<=cb(i,j) && cb(i,j)<=195 && 0.01<=hue(i,j) && hue(i,j)<=0.1 
          segment(i,j)=1; 
      else       
          segment(i,j)=0; 
      end    
  end
end
im(:,:,1)=I(:,:,1).*segment;   
im(:,:,2)=I(:,:,2).*segment; 
im(:,:,3)=I(:,:,3).*segment; 
%imshow(uint8(im));
title('My Edge Detection')
im1 = imclearborder(im2bw(im));
   figure 
imshow(im1)
im_fill = imfill(im1, 'holes');
figure 
imshow(im_fill)
 s = regionprops(im_fill, 'Area', 'PixelList');
 [~,ind] = max([s.Area]);
 pix = sub2ind(size(im), s(ind).PixelList(:,2), s(ind).PixelList(:,1));
 out = zeros(size(im));
 out(pix) = im(pix);
imshow(out);
```

***Here after subtracting the face , and finding out the largest connect area . 
I want to crop that area from the original image .***

Comment: Please expand your question with more information and/or add comments in your code so we can better help you.

Comment: @BrianLynch
 in the first part after subtracting the face through viola jones, then  i converted to Hue for finding out the skin color then ,after that  found out the largest connected region in binary image (hand) .
Now how can i crop that connected region area from the original input image .

Comment: Are you asking how to take the original image and turn all the pixels that are _not_ in the connected region black or something?

Comment: @BrianLynch i want to crop my hand portion from the whole image and use it for further image processing

Comment: Instead of trying to edit your code I have posted an example of how to crop out a part of the image identified with a boolean mask.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach to crop out the part of your image designed with the threshold mask.

Basically the code finds a part of the image that should be extracted based on some boolean value -- I am using `subPass` which has the height and width of the image and contains 1's for pixels that should be extracted and 0's for pixels that should be ignored.

Once you have that boolean matrix you can then use it to set the pixels you want to ignore as black (if that is what you want to do). Or, you can find the minimum and maximum indices that form a boundary around the target part to be extracted, then crop the image based on those indices (`I` and `J` in my code).

```
% load image
img = double(imread('sample.jpg'))/255;

% find some particular region... say all pixels that are nearly white
% this will be a matrix with 1's where the pixel passes the test
subPass = double((img(:,:,1) >= 0.95).*(img(:,:,2) >= 0.95).*(img(:,:,3) > 0.95));

% set all the pixels not in the target region to be black
imgNew = img;
imgNew(:,:,1) = img(:,:,1).*subPass;
imgNew(:,:,2) = img(:,:,2).*subPass;
imgNew(:,:,3) = img(:,:,3).*subPass;

% plot results
figure
image([img imgNew]);
axis equal;
axis tight

% find indices of target region
[I,J] = find(subPass == 1);

% crop target region based on min/max indices
imgNewCrop = imgNew(min(I):max(I),min(J):max(J),:);

% plot cropped image
figure
image(imgNewCrop);
axis equal
axis tight
```

You can use this image from [here](http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/iphone-4S-sample_1.jpg) (simply download and rename to "sample.jpg").